# CFrameWnd as HwndHost

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, mfc

We are trying to host our old MFC application in a WPF application. We want the MFC frame to be in the same WPF process and not hosting a separate exe. We can create a derived `CFrameWnd` class in the `HwndHost::BuildWindowCore()` and show it.

Tabbed MFC dialogs and controls are working fine, but not the toolbars and menu that are attached at the `CFrameWnd`. The routing of the `WM_COMMANDS` through the `CFrameWnd::OnCmdMsg` does not work, and we don’t get any update in the toolbar UI too. Trying to create a separate thread to run the `CWinApp::Run()` loop did not work because the function get stuck in a `PeekMessage()`.

We read the MS documentation, but it refers only to dialogs and controls. Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: Toolbar UI updates are handled in `CWinThread::OnIdle()` which broadcasts the `WM_IDLEUPDATECMDUI` message to its frame window and descendents. So this is probably the cause of the toolbar issue. As for the command routing this might also be caused by the lack of a `CWinApp` object that orchestrates the routing.